# Anonymous user with proftpd on fedora

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, ftp

I am trying to setup an anonymous user account on our server to enable people to downlaod technical manuals for our products etc. and I would like this to be as secure as possible!

I was just wondering if anyone knew a series of steps that will allow me to create an anonymous ftp account linked to a directory on the server that enables download only ? Also how could i make a corresponding ftp account with write priviledges to this account to allow people within our company to upload new files ?

Sorry i'm a bit new to all this!

Many Thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into creating an SFTP account that is locked into a chroot.  People can get in, download and upload, but everything is trapped and seperated from the machine.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6181828.html

Comment: You could also set up Webmin and then use that to create the ftp setup and lock the user to a certain folder and then set the umask of that user to more restrictive then normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this guide:

http://www.ls-l.net/ftp/