# Anonymous user with proftp on linux

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

I am trying to setup an anonymous user account on our server to enable people to download technical manuals for our products etc. and I would like this to be as secure as possible!

I was just wondering if anyone knew a series of steps that will allow me to create an anonymous FTP account linked to a directory on the server that enables download only?

Also how could I make a corresponding FTP account with write privileges to this account to allow people within our company to upload new files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anonymous user with proftpd on fedora](http://serverfault.com/questions/72947/anonymous-user-with-proftpd-on-fedora)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/example-conf.html).

Answer (score 0):

If security is a priority for you, you should consider to set up encrypted access to you FTP site. Some examples of mod_tls configuration for ProFTPd could be found [here](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/doc/contrib/ProFTPD-mini-HOWTO-TLS.html).

Hope that helps. Cheers.